# Browser prints empty in all browsers on a specific page containing Google Map

Tags: .net, google-maps, printing, printing-web-page

I have a project, where a single page is causing problems. As the title says, when printing this page from the browsers print function, only the information from the top and header show, all the content is empty.

The page has several tabs (using Telerik RadTabStrip and RadMultiPage), with various web user controls. One of these controls contain a map using Google Map Api, which when commented out solves the problem.

Anybody know exactly what in the Api thats causing this, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I was a bit fast in posting my problem. It turned out to be a javascript block with visibility:hidden set for the entire body under @media print.